# How can I return value from promise in ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am having problem getting values from an return http  response - I'm trying to use Promise to get data from web service but it says undefined when I previewed in console.

In the response body, this is what was return:

```
{"data":[{
     "loginStatus":"Valid",
     "CustomerName":"Fagbemi Ayodele",
     "Mobile":null,
     "Email":"fagbemiayodele48@gmail.com",
     "CustomerID":"3"
   }]}
```

**auth-service.ts**

```
login(credentials) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(apiUrl + '/login.php', JSON.stringify(credentials))
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res.json());

        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });

  }
```

**login.ts**

```
this.authService.login(this.loginData).then((result) => {
        this.data = result['data'];
        console.log("Result: "+ this.data.loginStatus);

        if (this.data.loginStatus == 'Valid') {
          localStorage.setItem('loginStatus', this.data.loginStatus);
          localStorage.setItem('CustomerName', this.data.CustomerName);
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(MyApp);
          this.loading.dismiss();
        }

        else {
          this.loading.dismiss();
        }
      }, (err) => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.presentToast(err);
      });
```

Comment: Maybe you are using it before the variable is set

Answer (score 0):

You `email` variable is local to `if` statement. Outside of `if` it will not be defined. Either access (print to console)  within `if`, or declare `email` outside of `if` - before `if`

Check the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2np649xv/)

Comment: Still undefined.

Comment: @FagbemiAyodele are you sure your globalData has valid data in it ? check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2np649xv/

Answer (score 0):

Please declare `var email=[];` outside `if` block.

If you want to check if your desired variable is declared before using it, try adding `"use strict";` as the first of your javascript file. After adding `"use strict";`, if you try using variable that is not in the scope, your script will throw an exception.
Refer to [use strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) documentation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did but still having undefined

Comment: Can you paste 

1. You console output after using "use strict"
2. your actual code after removing sensitive content ?

Answer (score 0):

As you have totally rewired your question ([Revision History](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61024042/revisions)), my previous answer is no more valid.

From your response body, it is clear that response object property `data` (`result['data']`) is `array`, not `object`.So, you can not access `this.data.loginStatus`.

You should use `this.data[0].loginStatus` to access login status from your API response.
Also, do not forget to check `length` of `data` (`data.length > 0`) before using it.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score -1):

The console is executing before the loop ends that's why it is getting blank. Use async-await for proper result.